# How to get the place address from specified latitude and longitude with Google Place API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm making a cab booking app like Uber,
User drag the map to choose his location with the pin,

And I grab the LatLng of that pin.

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            pinLocation = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            setPickupLocationPrefs(pinLocation);
        }
    });

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            updateLocationUI();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        updateLocationUI();
    }
}
```

I want to get the place address of that pin to show to my users if the app operate in that location or not (like uber does).

How can I get that address from pin location coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Reverse Geocoding. First get Latitude and Longitude from pin point. better to handle this in background thread. otherwise it will block UI.

```
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
try {
    List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getCountryName());
    }
    String Address=sb.toString());
}catch(Exception E);
```

**SOLUTION TO FIX UI BLOCKING**

Full example code using a Thread and a Handler to get the `Geocoder` answer without blocking the UI.

Geocoder call procedure, can be located in a Helper class

```
public static void getAddressFromLocation(
        final Location location, final Context context, final Handler handler) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());   
            String result = null;
            try {
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    // sending back first address line and locality
                    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            } finally {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.setTarget(handler);
                if (result != null) {
                    msg.what = 1;
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("address", result);
                    msg.setData(bundle);
                } else 
                    msg.what = 0;
                msg.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Here is the call to this Geocoder procedure in your UI `Activity/Fragment`:

```
getAddressFromLocation(PinPointLocation, mContext, new GeocoderHandler());
```

And the handler class within `Activity/Fragment` to show the results in your UI:

```
private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        String result;
        switch (message.what) {
        case 1:
            Bundle bundle = message.getData();
            result = bundle.getString("address");
            break;
        default:
            result = null;
        }
        // replace by what you need to do
        myLabel.setText(result);
    }   
}
```